# How can I restore To Do / Doing labels in a GitLab CE group board?

Tags: gitlab

I am running a GitLab EE instance with no extras, so it’s effectively GitLab CE. When I created my group board I was given the option to use the default To Do / Doing labels, or make my own. I opted to make my own. As far as I can tell this is not possible on GitLab CE, so now I have no labels on my board (apart from Open and Closed).

Comment: cross-posted: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/20828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily recreate these labels as follows:

1. Create them under “Labels”, then navigate back to “Boards”
2. Click the “Add list” button
3. Select the label from the dropdown, and it will appear in the board

(The columns in the board are known as both “labels” and “lists”.)